# Eigenvalues and eigenvector of a matrix containing $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$
    A
  = \begin{bmatrix}
                 0 &           1 & -\sin \theta \\
                -1 &           0 &  \cos \theta \\
      -\sin \theta & \cos \theta &            0
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
Given this matrix I want to calculate its eigenvalues and eigenvectors. What I don't understand is how this can be done because I find a characteristic polynomial of $\lambda^3 = 0$ which means that its eigenvalue is $0$ with algebraic multiplicity of $3$. When I perform the row operations to find the eigenvectors I can't because the top left element is $0$ so I can't eliminate the elements below it.

Comment: "which means that its eigenvalue is $0$ with geometric multiplicity of $3$" Nope, it  is the *algebraic* multiplicity that's $3$. The geometric multiplicity is $1$.

Comment: Exchanging rows is an elementary row operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a $0$ there, exchange the first and the second rows, thereby getting$$\begin{bmatrix}-1&0&\cos\theta\\0&1&\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta&0\end{bmatrix}.$$Now, proceed in the usual way. In the end, you will get that the eigenvectors with eigenvalue $a$ are those vectors of the form $\lambda(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,1)$.

Comment: My question is can this be done when I am trying to find the eigenvectors of any matrix?

Comment: @HarryTouloupas No. But it can be done when the eigenvalue is $0$.

Comment: @HarryTouloupas For an arbitrary matrix $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ you can perform row operations (also exchange of rows) on $A-\lambda I$ in order to find an eigenvector. Here, $\lambda$ is zero, so you do the stuff with $A$.

Comment: Also in this example why is $A^k = \vec0$ for every $k>=3$ ? I can see why  $A^k = \vec0$ but why do we need the $k>=3$?

Comment: @HarryTouloupas Because$$A^2=\begin{bmatrix}-\cos ^2(\theta ) & -\sin (\theta ) \cos (\theta ) & \cos (\theta ) \\-\sin (\theta ) \cos (\theta ) & -\sin ^2(\theta ) & \sin (\theta ) \\ -\cos (\theta ) & -\sin (\theta ) & 1\end{bmatrix}\neq0.$$

Comment: Is that enough to prove that $A^k = 0$ for $k>=3$?

Comment: @HarryTouloupas No, I was just explaining why is it that we don't have $A^k=0$ for every natutal $k$. On the other hand, you can prove that $A^3=0$ and deduce from it that $A^k=0$ whenever $k\geqslant3$.